# scrapy with payload request

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to get a POST request, but I don't know what's wrong with my code that the data doesn't come.

The following message is displayed:

> HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed

[This](https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiMGIwNTY2MjgtMzJhYy00MzEwLTk5MDAtYTI2MGVlMzk1NjM2IiwidCI6IjZmMGU5YzQyLTk2Y2UtNDU1MS05NzAxLWJhMzFkMGQ2ZDE5ZSJ9) is the website

A screenshot of the header:

[image: Header screenshot]

This is my code:

```
import json
import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'pb'
    payload = {"version":"1.0.0","queries":[{"Query":{"Commands":[{"SemanticQueryDataShapeCommand":{"Query":{"Version":2,"From":[{"Name":"e","Entity":"Events"},{"Name":"d","Entity":"DAX"}],"Select":[{"Column":{"Expression":{"SourceRef":{"Source":"e"}},"Property":"Date Start"},"Name":"Events.Date Start"},{"Column":{"Expression":{"SourceRef":{"Source":"e"}},"Property":"Event Type"},"Name":"Events.Event Type"},{"Column":{"Expression":{"SourceRef":{"Source":"e"}},"Property":"Name"},"Name":"Events.Name"},{"Measure":{"Expression":{"SourceRef":{"Source":"d"}},"Property":"Length"},"Name":"Events.Total Days"},{"Column":{"Expression":{"SourceRef":{"Source":"e"}},"Property":"Location"},"Name":"Events.Location"},{"Column":{"Expression":{"SourceRef":{"Source":"e"}},"Property":"Link to Event"},"Name":"Events.Link to Event"},{"Measure":{"Expression":{"SourceRef":{"Source":"d"}},"Property":"Days Until Event"},"Name":"DAX.Days Until"},{"Column":{"Expression":{"SourceRef":{"Source":"e"}},"Property":"Link to Submit"},"Name":"Events.Link to Submit"},{"Measure":{"Expression":{"SourceRef":{"Source":"d"}},"Property":"Event Type Number"},"Name":"DAX.Event Type Number"}],"OrderBy":[{"Direction":1,"Expression":{"Column":{"Expression":{"SourceRef":{"Source":"e"}},"Property":"Date Start"}}}]},"Binding":{"Primary":{"Groupings":[{"Projections":[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]}]},"DataReduction":{"DataVolume":3,"Primary":{"Window":{"Count":500}}},"Aggregates":[{"Select":3,"Aggregations":[{"Min":{}},{"Max":{}}]}],"SuppressedJoinPredicates":[8],"Version":1}}}]},"CacheKey":"{\"Commands\":[{\"SemanticQueryDataShapeCommand\":{\"Query\":{\"Version\":2,\"From\":[{\"Name\":\"e\",\"Entity\":\"Events\"},{\"Name\":\"d\",\"Entity\":\"DAX\"}],\"Select\":[{\"Column\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"Source\":\"e\"}},\"Property\":\"Date Start\"},\"Name\":\"Events.Date Start\"},{\"Column\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"Source\":\"e\"}},\"Property\":\"Event Type\"},\"Name\":\"Events.Event Type\"},{\"Column\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"Source\":\"e\"}},\"Property\":\"Name\"},\"Name\":\"Events.Name\"},{\"Measure\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"Source\":\"d\"}},\"Property\":\"Length\"},\"Name\":\"Events.Total Days\"},{\"Column\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"Source\":\"e\"}},\"Property\":\"Location\"},\"Name\":\"Events.Location\"},{\"Column\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"Source\":\"e\"}},\"Property\":\"Link to Event\"},\"Name\":\"Events.Link to Event\"},{\"Measure\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"Source\":\"d\"}},\"Property\":\"Days Until Event\"},\"Name\":\"DAX.Days Until\"},{\"Column\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"Source\":\"e\"}},\"Property\":\"Link to Submit\"},\"Name\":\"Events.Link to Submit\"},{\"Measure\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"Source\":\"d\"}},\"Property\":\"Event Type Number\"},\"Name\":\"DAX.Event Type Number\"}],\"OrderBy\":[{\"Direction\":1,\"Expression\":{\"Column\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"Source\":\"e\"}},\"Property\":\"Date Start\"}}}]},\"Binding\":{\"Primary\":{\"Groupings\":[{\"Projections\":[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]}]},\"DataReduction\":{\"DataVolume\":3,\"Primary\":{\"Window\":{\"Count\":500}}},\"Aggregates\":[{\"Select\":3,\"Aggregations\":[{\"Min\":{}},{\"Max\":{}}]}],\"SuppressedJoinPredicates\":[8],\"Version\":1}}}]}","QueryId":"","ApplicationContext":{"DatasetId":"6427f3c6-42f6-4287-b061-c31c1d2e7ae0","Sources":[{"ReportId":"6e442642-8594-4894-bc32-0ab7f4620772"}]}}],"cancelQueries":[],"modelId":1226835}
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url='https://wabi-australia-southeast-api.analysis.windows.net/public/reports/querydata?synchronous=true',
            method='POST',
            body=json.dumps(self.payload),
            headers={

                'Accept-Language': 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
                'ActivityId': '1d3ecdc2-5dc0-801e-4140-82a258f127a6',
                'Connection': 'keep-alive',
                'Content-Length': '3462',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                'Host': 'wabi-australia-southeast-api.analysis.windows.net',
                'Origin': 'https://app.powerbi.com',
                'Referer': 'https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiMGIwNTY2MjgtMzJhYy00MzEwLTk5MDAtYTI2MGVlMzk1NjM2IiwidCI6IjZmMGU5YzQyLTk2Y2UtNDU1MS05NzAxLWJhMzFkMGQ2ZDE5ZSJ9',
                'RequestId': '11c18fe6-00da-7df4-952c-98ba7bdf188e',
                'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
                'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'cross-site',
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36',
                'X-PowerBI-ResourceKey': '0b056628-32ac-4310-9900-a260ee395636'
            }
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        items = json.loads(response.text)
        yield {"data":items}
```

Answer (score 1):

The request in your screenshot is a `GET` request.

The behaviour of this website is very interesting!
Let's examine it.

By looking at the network panel we can see that GET request is being made to some complex url with many various headers. However It seems that the header `X-PowerBI-ResourceKey` is the only one that's needed and it controls what content the request will return.

So all we need to replicate this is find the `X-PowerBI-ResourceKey` value.
If you take a look at the source code of the html page:
https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiMGIwNTY2MjgtMzJhYy00MzEwLTk5MDAtYTI2MGVlMzk1NjM2IiwidCI6IjZmMGU5YzQyLTk2Y2UtNDU1MS05NzAxLWJhMzFkMGQ2ZDE5ZSJ9
[image: source page of powerbi.com]

Here we can see that javascript's `atob` method is used on url parameter. This is javascripts b64decode function. We can run it in python:

```
$ ptpython                                                                                                            
>>> from base64 import b64decode                                                                                      
>>> b64decode("eyJrIjoiMGIwNTY2MjgtMzJhYy00MzEwLTk5MDAtYTI2MGVlMzk1NjM2IiwidCI6IjZmMGU5YzQyLTk2Y2UtNDU1MS05NzAxLWJhMzF
  1 kMGQ2ZDE5ZSJ9")                                                                                                   
b'{"k":"0b056628-32ac-4310-9900-a260ee395636","t":"6f0e9c42-96ce-4551-9701-ba31d0d6d19e"}'
```

We got it figured out! Now lets put everything together in our crawler:

```py
import json
from base64 import b64decode

from w3lib.url import url_query_parameter 

def parse(self, response):

    url = "https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiMGIwNTY2MjgtMzJhYy00MzEwLTk5MDAtYTI2MGVlMzk1NjM2IiwidCI6IjZmMGU5YzQyLTk2Y2UtNDU1MS05NzAxLWJhMzFkMGQ2ZDE5ZSJ9"
    # get the "r" paremeter from url
    resource_key = url_query_parameter(url, 'r')  
    # base64 decode it
    resource_key = b64decode(resource_key)
    # {'k': '0b056628-32ac-4310-9900-a260ee395636', 't': '6f0e9c42-96ce-4551-9701-ba31d0d6d19e'}
    # it's a json string - load it and get key "k"
    resource_key = json.loads(resource_key)['k']


    headers = {
        'Accept': "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        # 'X-PowerBI-ResourceKey': "0b056628-32ac-4310-9900-a260ee395636",
        'X-PowerBI-ResourceKey': resource_key,
        'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36",
        'Accept-Encoding': "gzip, deflate, br",
        'Accept-Language': "en-US,en;q=0.9,lt;q=0.8,et;q=0.7,de;q=0.6",
        }

    yield Request(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: I didn't understand how my spider would look. Here is a picture of how it is currently.
https://imgur.com/a/hQPDsAo